# unbiased estimates and MLE of central moments and of standardized moments?

Tags: estimation, moments

I have heard of unbiased estimate and MLE of variance, and some about those of kurtosis. Are there general results about

- unbiased estimates of k-th order [central moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment)?
- MLE of k-th order central moments?
- unbiased estimates of k-th order [standardized moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_moment)?
- MLE of k-th order standardized moments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- Yes, they can be constructed, although they are not simple. See http://www.jstor.org/stable/2985201 .
- Using the [invariance of the MLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance), it follows that the MLE of the k-th order central moments and the k-th order central moments is simply obtaining by plugging the MLE into the expression of the corresponding quantities of interest. For instance $\hat{\mu} = \int x f(x;\hat{\theta})dx$

Comment: Thanks! For standardized moments, is its MLE  also obtained by the invariance of MLE, and how about its unbiased estimates?